# Assertion error with JBox2D in Processing

Tags: java, processing, box2d, game-physics, assertion

Having issues with JBox2D trying to set a fixed rotation for bodies I'm introducing into a game I've created.

The idea is to be able to change options in a game screen. You click on the screen to introduce a building block and, while the mouse is held down, the arrow keys are pressed to change the orientation of the block - a little like tetris.

This seems simple enough, but I'm working with a physical body and a library I'm not that familiar with. I've tried using the .setFixRotation method in the code to keep the rotation fixed for a time to allow building of a tower, after which the fixed rotation will be turned off to allow regular physics to apply. The code I've tried using is here:

(Placed within the building block class as a method)

```
  void changeOrientation()
  {
    Vec2 pos = box2d.getBodyPixelCoord(body);

    if (currentBuildingBlockOption == 0)
    body.setTransform(pos, 0);

    if (currentBuildingBlockOption == 1)
    body.setTransform(pos, 90);

    if (currentBuildingBlockOption == 2)
    body.setTransform(pos, -45);

    if (currentBuildingBlockOption == 3)
    body.setTransform(pos, 45);
  }
```

within the draw() function, there's:

```
  void updateBlockChoice()
  { 
    if (buildingBlocks.size()>0) 
    { 
      BuildingBlock currentBlock = buildingBlocks.get(buildingBlocks.size()-1);

      if (mousePressed==true)
      {
        currentBlock.changeOrientation();
      }
    }
  }
```

With this code, as soon as I release the mouse button, the whole thing crashes and freezes and the console says how I can't run the code because of an assertion error. If anyone has any suggestions or knows a lot about JBox2d, please don't hesitate to give any advice or correct me anywhere I've gone wrong. Thanks!